# How to implement Mailchimp's method for automatically tracking email opens?

Tags: php, email

Emails containing requested reminders are sent to users daily. My goal is to create a calendar in each marking days in which they opened the email in green. This requires **tracking whether the user opens or does not open their email on a given day.**

Mailchimp present their method in [a blog post](http://kb.mailchimp.com/reports/about-open-tracking)

> *When you send campaigns through MailChimp, we embed a tiny invisible graphic in the bottom of your HTML email... When someone opens your email and views the images within it, that
>   graphic is downloaded from our server, and it's recorded as an open on
>   your campaign report.*

To break this process down into steps:

1) Including graphic in each email (sent with chron job) unique to user
2) Writing a script that runs whenever the graphic is downloaded from the server and changes an "email_opened" value in a User History table

So my questions:

·How does #1 work? Furthermore, how can I create a system for automatically generating a unique graphic for each user? 
My current idea is to send the image from a table using PHP such as:

```
<? $img_data = file_get_contents("images/phpimage.png"); header("Content-type: image/png"); echo $img_data; ?>
```

and then somehow set it up to send a different image depending on the email address.

·Where should script #2 be placed and in which language should it be written? My initial thought was php and within the email, but if it's the moment the graphic is downloaded from the server then surely it should be server-side. How would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "include" an image in an HTML-format email, what you actually have to do is create an `<img>` tag where the `src` attribute contains a URL which points back to an image file on your server. (You can't run PHP "within the email", as you contemplated, btw).

For this purpose though, the image could be invisible (using style properties, or by setting height/width to 0), and the `src` could actually point to a script on your web server which accepts a user ID and email ID as parameters and renders an empty image. The unique URL could be something like `http://www.example.com/logEmail?userID=12345&emailID=6789` for a particular user/email combination. The image content that you return from this script is not important and does not need to be unique - remember, it's invisible anyway. Just return a 1px by 1px white square.

When the script runs, before it renders the image back and completes the request, it simply updates your database at the same time with to indicate that the email with the given ID has been read by the user with the given ID.

As for the language, that's entirely up to you depending on how/where you're planning to host the web application. You can achieve what you want in any of the popular server-side languages.

The MailChimp article you linked to makes an important caveat though - this technique won't work if you send any users emails in plain-text for any reason, and nor will it work if the user's mail client is not set to download images (corporate Outlook installs are often set like this by default, for instance, until the user clicks to allow them to be downloaded, and/or marks the sender as safe). So you can't rely on this data as a 100% accurate guide to whether your users are reading your emails or not. If you get a response for a particular email, you can say with certainty that they opened it (N.B. "opening" and "reading" and "understanding" are absolutely not the same thing!!). But if you don't get a response, you cannot in fact be certain whether they opened the email or not.